# Select all x in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I was just wondering how to select all x in word,

I am specifically thinking about:

- all formulas
- all images
- all legends
- all results of a search query

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is too broad now, and it's unlikely to be answered correctly. Please edit it and clarify. What formula, search query means for you in Word? "all images" - do you want to do OCR???

Comment: what is OCR ? I just want to change the style/alignement of all images / equations at once.